# Open excluded files and folders in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2

For most day to day uses it's helpful to hide system files and config files from Sublime Text 2 via the `file_exclude_patterns` and `folder_exclude_patterns`, but every so often I'll need to make a quick change in those files.  Is there anyway to temporarily show those files so I can access them in the sidebar and goto anything (cmd-p) without having to edit my settings file?

Comment: You could use projects to do this. Have Project_A and a Project_A_Config. Then you can switch between them without the clutter.